# How do I post my array in my firebase database?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a fantasy soccer web app based on a local league. So far, when a user is created using firebase auth, there is a respective node created in my firebase using the user uid as follows:

```
users:{
     user UID: {
                email:
                teamname:
                fullname:
                week:
              }
   }
```

I have an empty array called $scope.history and a buy function for each selected player:

```
$scope.history = [];


$scope.buy = function(player) {

  $scope.total = 50000000;     

    //remove if already added
    var index = $scope.history.indexOf(player);
    if(index>=0){
        $scope.history.splice(index,1);
        return;
    }

    //max 6 allowed
    if($scope.history.length>=6){
        alert('max 6 allowed');
        return;
    }

    var selected = $scope.history.reduce(function(a,b){
        a[b.position] = (a[b.position] || 0) + 1;
        return a;
    }, {}) || {};

    if(!selected[player.position] || selected[player.position]<2){
        $scope.history.push(player);
    }else{
        alert('You can add only two players per position');
    }
  };

  $scope.getTotal = function(){
    return $scope.history.reduce(function(tot, p){
        tot = tot - p.price;
        return tot;
    }, $scope.total);
  };
```

MY Issue

My issue is when the user selects the 6 player array (each player is a JSON object), how do I get that array posted to the "week" child node under the respective user's user UID parent node?

I have tried doing this but was unsuccessful:

```
    $scope.saveTeam = function(){
    var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("users/" + auth.uid + "/week"); 
     ref2.set($scope.history);
     };
```

Is there a way to get each user's 6 player selection to be posted to the "week" node such that each week, the selection can be changed/ updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the update function. If you use push or set it will create new node under the week and there it will keep your array but if you use update it will store directly.

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('users').child(userUID).child('week');
ref.update($scope.history);
```

It will store the data like this:
[image]

Comment: thanks. The issue with this is that when the user makes a selection for the following week, the update function will override what the previous week's selection was. But I want to be able to see what the previous selection was. I think arrays cannot be posted using the set function. It seems to not work using set.

Comment: Yes, you can post an array using the set funcion. It will create or update the node. I don't understand what are you trying to do. If you want to keep track of the previous weeks maybe what you need is to redesign you're schema. Now you're overwriting the content of the week so if you want to add the new  week but keep the previous you should have multiples nodes inside week.

Comment: I tried your method and it was unsuccessful. I tried posting random words and it worked. I also tried posting specific players from the array using $scope.history [0], but it didnt work either.